# How to create li elements automatically by php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Recently, I have built a website by wordpress.  I have created a sidebar using ul...li elements.  I wrote the code manually like the following.

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li id="one"><a href="#one">2010 News</a>
        <?php query_posts('order=ASC&cat=2&tag=2010&orderby=date'); ?>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>  
        <?php endwhile;?> 
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="two"><a href="#two">2011 News</a>
        <?php query_posts('order=ASC&cat=2&tag=2011&orderby=date'); ?>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>  
        <?php endwhile;?> 
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I just want the code to create the **2012 News**,**2013 News** section automatically by adding the li element when someone has posted a new page in the category whose id is 2 and sign the tag with 2012 or 2013.  I can modify the code by myself, but others may not know how to modify it.  So I just want to make it easier for others.  Can anyone help me?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="accordion">
   <?php for ($year = 2010; $year < date('Y'); $year++) { ?>
    <li id="one"><a href="#<?php echo $year;?>"><?php echo $year;?> News</a>
        <?php query_posts("order=ASC&cat=2&tag=$year&orderby=date"); ?>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>  
            <?php endwhile; ?> 
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It works very well!Now my friend can post any page without edit the html code.It is really nice!